# Indexing Variables with Loops

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, indexing

In my code, I am trying insert values into a dictionary by indexing values in a listed and a nested list( two separate inputs).

```
def list_to_dict(titles, nested_list):
    nobel_awards = {}

    index = 0 

    for i in nested_list:
        year_category = {}
        year_category[titles[1]] = nested_list[i][1]
        year_category[titles[2]] = nested_list[i][2]
        nobel_awards[nested_list[i][0]] = year_category 

    return nobel_awards
```

It returns me an error stating 'list indices must be integers, slicers'

I'm confused about why.

Comment: Do you have example of data?

Comment: Can you show us how the nested list looks like and what you are trying to accomplish. This way, it would be easier to help you improve your code and make it work.

Comment: The error occurs because you put something into `[]` not integer or not slicer. So it is important what data in parameters.

Comment: `nested_list[i][1]` → `i[1]`?

Comment: when you're assigning those nested list 'values' to actual dictionary 'values' you can't assign the key's of the dictionary like that either. and it's not pythonic to iterate through the list within the list by using list an iterable that is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

What I can understand from your code is that you're trying to create dicts from a list of keys(titles) and from a list of lists.

In python you can use the function zip() to do this. In your case it would look something like this:

```
def list_to_dict(titles, nested_list):
    nobel_awards = {}
    for award in nested_list:
        year_category = dict(zip(titles, award))
        nobel_awards[year_category['name']] = year_category
    return nobel_awards


nested_list = [['Test', 'title'], ['test2', 'title2']]
titles = ['name', 'title']
result = list_to_dict(titles, nested_list)

print(result)
```

Where the result would look like this:

```
{'Test': {'name': 'Test', 'title': 'title'}, 'test2': {'name': 'test2', 'title': 'title2'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are accessing the list with the value of the list and not by the index of it. You can use the `enumerate()` function in the loop and replace the `i` variable with the index of the list. For example:

```
for index, value in enumerate(nested_list):
    ''' Your code here '''
    year_category[titles[1]] = nested_list[index][1] #sample
    ...
```

I don't know what does the two parameters' content look like but the error 'list indices must be integers, slicers' will be addressed by accessing the list by the index just like the sample above.